# jQuery add new div element for each 3 div element and for each 6 div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

First all i'm new on `jQuery` so my question is not relevant please forgive me.
I have some `div` elements in my Dom and i'm trying to make a book shelf for my products. I followed **[this fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/7h2JKXv40U)** and that works perfectly. But my products are coming from `MySQL` and i'm parsing them with `foreach` loop in `PHP`.

My HTML Looks like:

```
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div>
```

**Question:** How can i add new `<div>` element after `each` 3 `<div>` like;

```
<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
```

And add new `<div>` element after `each` 6 `<div>` like;

```
<div class="col-xs-12 shelf"></div>
```

**Shortly,** desired HTML output;

```
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div>
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<!-- Here Is The After 3rd div -->
<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
<!-- Here Is The After 3rd div -->
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<div class="product-yarn col-xs-4 col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="book-shelf"></a>
</div> 
<!-- Here Is The After 6th div -->
<div class="col-xs-12 shelf"></div>
<!-- Here Is The After 6th div -->
```

I looked at some questions in `SO` some of them about `wrapping` every 3 element with new element. But i want to add new element.

So, Is it possible to make it with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/UJA2zbdYPz#

Comment: @madalinivascu http://jsfiddle.net/L9c4ybkt/ look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) in conjunction with [`:nth-child()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> `.after()`
>
> > Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> `:nth-child()`
>
> > Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".product-yarn:nth-child(3n)").after('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg">after 3th div</div>');
    $(".shelf:odd").removeClass('hidden-md hidden-lg');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ymgdngxd/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product-yarn:nth-child(3n)").after('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg">after 3th div</div>');
  $(".shelf:odd").removeClass('hidden-md');
  $(".shelf:odd").removeClass('hidden-lg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">1</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">2</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">3</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">4</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">5</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">6</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">1</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">2</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">3</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">4</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">5</a>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 product-yarn"> <a href="#" class="book-shelf">6</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
    $('div.col-xs-4').each(function (i, v) {
     var index = parseInt($(this).index());
     if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 6 != 0)) {
         $('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>').insertBefore($(this));
     } else if (i / 6 != 0 && i % 6 == 0) {
         $('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf"></div>').insertBefore($(this));
     }

 });
 $('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf"></div>').insertAfter('div.col-xs-4:last');
```

http://www.bootply.com/GITjvbYqiq

Comment: now it's counting 3rd div added via jquery, it's inserting 6th element  wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** :- 
The jquery code you would need is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".col-md-2").each(function (index, value) {
        if ((index + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            $(this).after('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg">after 3rd div</div>');
        }
        if ((index + 1) % 6 == 0) {
            $(this).after('<div class="col-xs-12 shelf">after 6th div</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

You can also check the working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/esrab6dd/1/
(text is added within links for demo purpose , you can have it removed)

Comment: thanks for answer. But your append is adding elements inside divs. take a look at my desired html output.

Comment: @HddnTHA - I have updated my solution as well as the demo , can you have a look into , i hope this is what u are looking for -http://jsfiddle.net/esrab6dd/1/

Comment: thank you. but after adding element, it's counting added elements and adding new ones to wrong place

Comment: @HddnTHA - http://jsfiddle.net/esrab6dd/3/ , i added more divs to the demo , the first condition adds a desired div after each 3rd & second loop after each 6th element. it is not taking the class of added elements. If you still have issues can you provide the desired output

Comment: thanks for the answer but i found the solution myself on other answer's fiddle. see this; http://jsfiddle.net/ymgdngxd/2/

Comment: @HddnTHA - glad you find the solution , but mine will work also same if you remove the second if condition. check the updated demo -http://jsfiddle.net/esrab6dd/4/. In your question it was asked to add '<div class="col-xs-12 shelf"></div>' after each 6th div

Comment: yeah but i have desired html output on my question. Btw thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            total_elements = $(".col-xs-4.col-md-2").length;
            var append_div = '<div class="col-xs-12 shelf hidden-md hidden-lg">  </div>';

            for (var i=3; i<total_elements; i+3){
                    $(".col-xs-4.col-md-2").eq(i).append(append_div);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it's giving console error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).length is not a function`

Comment: @HddnTHA `length` is a property not a function thus you are getting answer

Comment: @HddnTHA yup Satpal is right. Use length instead of length(). My bad,  sorry